# How to use wildcards within logrotate configuration files

Tags: linux, unix, syslog, logrotate

I have the following configuration that is not working:

1) Using rsyslog with Centos 5.
2) Inside /etc/logrotate.d I have the file sj-piers-logs.

SJ-PIERS-LOGS:

```
/syslogrep/sjpiers-logs/0* {
weekly
missingok
notifempty
dateext
copytruncate
compress
olddir /syslogbackup/sjpiers-logs/backup
rotate 96
}
```

4) logrotate.conf have the default configuration:

LOGROTATE.CONF

```
weekly
rotate 4
create
include /etc/logrotate.d
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    minsize 1M
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

5) Syslogs are sent by network devices to /syslogrep. I want to rotate the log file, compress and move it to /syslogbackup.

I was told that the error reside in the use of wildcards in sj-piers-logs file but it seems that I can use them according the the man page. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You say "not working" but you don't say exactly how. What *does* happen? What errors do you get?

Comment: Also you have 1), 2), 4) and 5). Where's 3)?

Comment: Kyle,
Nothing is happening the log files are not rotated and moved to /syslogbackup

Dennis,
Sorry about the typo. syslogrep and syslogbackup and everything inside have drwxrwxrwx but that is when they are listed as root. As a separate note using samba I can not read /syslogrep files from windows machine.

hayalci:

I run the command you gave me and it returned an error:

error: sjpiers-logs:12 olddir /syslogbackup/sjpiers-logs/backup and log file /syslogrep/sjpiers-logs/00-emerg are on different devices.

Each is mounted in different partitions.

Comment: well, you have your answer then. You should keep old logs and current ones under the same partition to achieve atomic "mv" capability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a test run with

```
 logrotate -f -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

It will provide you with an error message, or you can further investigate the logrotate configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem is if your `olddir` doesn't exist or has the wrong permissions. It will not be handled by `missingok`.